# Executing both php and javascript in ajax file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need ajax to run a script of both php and javascript in the background.

```
$.ajax("j_update.php");
```

And then: j_update.php:

```
//-> Get an XML file
$xmldata = simplexml_load_file('datafile.xml');

//->Look through
foreach($xmldata->user as $user) {

    echo "
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        animateOther(".$user->ip.", ".$user->left.", ".$user->top.");
        spectrumOther(".$user->ip.");
        </script>";

}
```

But (as I expected) this is impossible, the javascript doesn't get executed. I'm not sure what the correct way around it would be though... Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `$.ajax("j_update.php");`, use `$.getScript("j_update.php");` and erase the `<script>` open/close tags in the php file. Also remember to add `header("Content-type: application/javascript");` at the very top of your php script.

Answer (score 0):

Use [$.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) instead of $.ajax() to ensure the JavaScript runs.